# ¿Qué se debe hacer con las respuestas que solicitan voto a favor y/o que solicitan aprobar la respuesta?

Tags: discusión, convenciones-sociales

Me he encontrado respuestas que al final incluyen algo parecido a esto:

> Si te ha servido dale +1 y márcala cómo válida, si no contáctame por los comentarios

Esto podría generar un ambiente de tipo foro, lo cual no es la definición de SOes.

¿Qué se debe hacer en estos casos?

Comment: No acabo de entender la frase _Esto podría generar un ambiente de tipo foro, lo cual no es la definición de SOes_.

Comment: Dicho lo cual, creo que este comentario es pertinente si se pone _como comentario_ y después de que el OP indique que le ha funcionado. Si es parte de la respuesta, elimínalo porque no tiene nada que ver con la respuesta en sí.

Comment: @fedorqui Tu comentario bien podría ser una respuesta.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En ocasiones un usuario encuentra la solución a su problema en alguna respuesta, y la persona que realizó la respuesta pide al OP la marque como válida si le fue de ayuda, ya que en ocasiones se desconoce este procedimiento cuando somos nuevos en el sitio, sin embargo ese tipo de comentarios no son de utilidad posteriormente, por lo cual pueden ser eliminados.

De hecho el mismo texto de sugerencia para agregar comentarios indica evitarlo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso mucho menor utilidad tiene si se agrega al cuerpo de la **respuesta**, esto no esta prohibido pero en realidad como comentas, debería ser un comentario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin duda esto puede ser perjudicial para el que responde ya de alguna manera le resta calidad  a su respuesta.

**En cuanto a los comentarios, si encuentras un comentario que sea obsoleto, o innecesario, puedes reportarlo para que sea eliminado.**

Comment: Excelente respuesta!

Comment: creo que falta hacer la diferencia entre el comentario que pide marcarla como la respuesta aceptada cuando el op dice que funcionó, versus el que también diga que le vote positivo. Marcarla como aceptada tiene un sentido y propósito para la comunidad, por lo que comentar al respecto no lo veo malo; pedir un voto positivo en cambio, tiene mucho más que ver con querer ganar rep

Comment: @Lamak muy cierto. Yo he publicado varios comentarios en los que recuerdo al OP que debería marcar una respuesta como solución si la misma le arregla su problema... a veces esa respuesta es mía y a veces no y no creo que esos comentarios sean contraproducentes sino más bien informativos

Comment: Aquí se dan valoraciones sobre lo útil o poco útil que es poner esos textos en una respuesta pero no se responde a la pregunta del autor original. *¿Qué se debe hacer en estos casos?* ¿Debe reportar respuestas con ese texto? ¿Editarlas para eliminarlo? ¿Votar negativo? ¿No hacer nada? ¿Alguna otra cosa?